# Кнопка-картинка в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно сделать кнопку, но не стандартную, а другой формы, можно круглую, в идеале подставить картинку. Думал сделать как-то так, но у Label нет 'command'

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = tkinter.Tk()

img_name = 'pic.png'

img = Image.open(img_name)
img_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

label = tkinter.Label(win, image=img_photo, command=lambda: print('test'))
label.place(x=0, y=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Делайте не через command, а через bind на клик левой кнопкой, например.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы картинку на кнопке нарисовать, достаточно её как `image` параметр передать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from PIL import ImageTk  # $ pip install pillow

root = Tk()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
Button(root, image=image, command=lambda: print('click')).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Это понятно, надо было именно не наложить на кнопку, а чтобы картинка нажималась. Надо добавить

    def ok(event): print("ok")

и забиндить Label, как посоветовали выше

    label = tkinter.Label(win, image=img_photo) 
    label.bind("<Button-1>", ok)
    label.place(x=0, y=0)

Comment: @swaq посмотрите на заголовок вопроса. Мой ответ для людей из гугла с похожей проблемой (основная аудитория Stack Overflow). Вы всегда можете свой ответ, который вас помог, опубликовать (и принять).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы `Label` реагировал на клик мышью, достаточно привязать вызов нужной функции к событию "клик мышью" (в данном случае клик левой кнопкой мыши):

```
...

label = tkinter.Label(win, image=img_photo)
label.place(x=0, y=0)
label.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: print('test'))

win.mainloop()
```

`_` в lambda — игнорируемый параметр. Обработчики событий (привязываемые через `bind`) в отличие от обработчиков нажатий на кнопки (command) должны принимать параметр `event`. В данном случае мы этот параметр принимаем, но игнорируем.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите гладкую современную кнопочку, то сделайте relief='flat' (задает плоский рельеф)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from PIL import ImageTk  # $ pip install pillow

root = Tk()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
Button(root, image=image, command=lambda: print('click'), relief = 'flat').pack()
root.mainloop()
```